# Revert to old object state in Java

Tags: java, oop

I'm just learning Java but I keep running into the same problem over and over again

How do i revert to an old state of some object efficiently?

```
public class Example {
    MyObject myLargeObject;

    public void someMethod(){
        MyObject myLargeMyObjectRecovery = myLargeObject;

        /**
         * Update and change myLargeObject
         */

        if(someCondition){
            //revert to previous state of myLargeObject
            myLargeObject = myLargeMyObjectRecovery;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is how I would like the code to work but it obviously doesn't since myLargeObject and myLargeObjectRecovery are references to the same object.

One solution is to create a copy constructor. This is fine for small objects but if I have a large object (in my project the object is a large 2D array meaning I would have to iterate over all of the entries), this way feels wrong.

This must be a very common problem in Java, how do others get around it?

Comment: Nobody gets around it easily and there is no simple solution to selectively undo only the changes.

Comment: The need to do this motivated the invention of [software transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory). This is not a standard part of Java, but there are apparently libraries you can bring in that implement it somehow.

Comment: You can try Object.clone() method to get a copy of your object. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 1):

Either deep copy, as you noted, or possibly serialization.  You could store a serialized string, and then reconstruct the object from it later.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution depends on whether you have external references to your `MyObject` instance or not.

If you use the `myLargeObject` **from the `Example` class only**, you can use

- Serialize your object at the savepoint, and deserialize at the restore point (the serialized `byte[]` must be `transient`)
- Create a new instance with a Copy Constructor (doing deep copying) at the savepoint, and replace the reference at the restore point.

If you have access to the `MyObject` instance **from outside**, then it becomes a bit more interesting, you must introduce synchronization.

- All of your methods on `MyObject` must be `synchronized` (to avoid inconsistent read)
- You should have a `synchronized void saveState()` method which saves your state (either by *serialization*, or by *copy constructor*) (the latter is better)
- You should have a `synchronized void restoreState()`, where you internally restore your state (for copying fields you can use a common code fragment with the copy constructor)

In all cases it is recommended to *close the transaction* (kind of `commit()`) at some point, it means that when you get there, you can delete the saved state.

Also, it is very important, that if you have an underlying data structure, **you should traverse the whole structure** for it. Otherwise you may experience problems with the object references.

Be careful with *JPA Entities* or any externally-managed objects, it is unlikely that any of these methods will work with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a object to another, jvm refers to same object in the memory. Therefore, the changes on the object will be in the other objetc which references.

```
MyObject myLargeMyObjectRecovery = myLargeObject;
```

It is the same in your code. `myLargeMyObjectRecovery` and `myLargeObject` refer to same object in the memory.

If you want to exact copy of any object you can use Object.clone() method. this method will copy the object and return a object which is refer to another object whose fields and their valus same as the coppied object.

Since clone method is protected you can not access it direcly. you can implement a Prototype pattern depending on your requirements.

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/prototype-pattern.html

```
public class MyObject{

//fields, getters, setters and other methods.

public MyObject doClone()
    {
        MyObject clonedObject = this.clone(); //you may need to override clone()depending on your requirements.
return clonedObject;
    }

    }
```

and call it in your code

```
MyObject myLargeMyObjectRecovery = myLargeObject.doClone();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Memento Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/memento-pattern.html) addresses the design issue of the revert to previous state problem. This approach is useful when you need to capture one or multiple states of the object and be able to revert to them. Think of it as an N-step undo operation, just like in a text editor.

In the pattern you have a stateful object `Originator`, which is responsible for saving and restoring snapshots of it's state. The sate itself is saved in a wrapper class called `Memento`, which are stored in and accessed via the `CareTaker`.

In this approach the easiest idea is to deep-copy your objects. However this may be inefficient regarding performance and space, since you store whole objects and not the change-sets only.

Some object persistence libraries provide implementations of transactions and snapshots. Take a look at [Prevayler](http://prevayler.org/), which is an object persistence library for java and an implementation of the [prevalent system pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Prevalence). The library captures the changes to your objects in form of transactions and stores them in-memory. If you need a persistent storage of your POJOs, you can save snapshots of your objects on disk periodically and revert to them if needed.

You can find more on serializing POJOs in this SO question: [Is there a object-change-tracking/versioning Java API out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044476/is-there-a-object-change-tracking-versioning-java-api-out-there)