# Comparing objects deeply and presenting the differences in a webpage

Tags: java, object, comparison

I'm stuck with a problem of comparing objects deeply and highlighting the differences in a webpage. It has 4 domain classes, `ServerTypes`, `Server`, `Components` & `Properties`. All these are connected by beans.

Below are the code snippets of above domain classes.

```
  class ServerTypes {

    private List<Server> server;

    //getters&setters
}

    class Server {

    private List<Components> components; 
    //getters & setters
   } 

    class Components {

    private List<Properties> properties;
    //getters & setters

    }

    class Properties {
    private List<String> prop;
    //getters & setters

}
```

*ServerTypes- > Server ->Components-> Properties*

Beans depend on the above hierarchy. I've to loop through each property of the service class, extract the data and then compare with the ones present in a config file.

Comparison is done on all the objects of  *ServerTypes, Server, Components and Properties* classes.

Now, coming to problem, I'm feeling difficulty in looping through each object and doing a deeper comparison and on top of this, I'm struggling to show the differences in webpage with this approach.

Is there any suggestion from talents here to do it in a sensible and easier way rather looping through each object and doing a crude comparison?

I've tried to present this in the best possible way I can. If it is still unclear, kindly let me know, I'm happy to edit the question for you.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**(1) Object comparison**

You could try [javers](http://javers.org/documentation/diff-examples/):

I've never used it, but what I see looks good. I took an example from their site (here)

```
Diff diff = javers.compare(person1, person2);

List<ValueChange> changesByType = diff.getChangesByType(ValueChange.class);
for (ValueChange valueChange : changesByType) {
    System.out.println(valueChange);
}
```

Output:

> ValueChange{globalId:'Person/#pets/0', property:'name', oldVal:'cat',
>   newVal:'dog'} ValueChange{globalId:'Person/#pets/0', property:'age',
>   oldVal:'1', newVal:'2'}

Another other answers on this: [Is there a Java library that can "diff" two Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001400/is-there-a-java-library-that-can-diff-two-objects)

---

**(2) Json comparison**

You could also convert your object to json in order to perform the comparison. Then, the diff becomes a simple text comparison.

---

**(3) How to display**

As for how to display it, I would take a look at how others are displaying online comparison:

- http://prettydiff.com
- http://www.quickdiff.com
- ...