# If condition then put value many times in java

Tags: java, if-statement, compare

I have two objects with many parameters.
I need to compare it by each field and put information about what field is different

How to do it clean?

I'm not happy with something like that

```
if(<condition>) {
    list.add(object.getParam());
}
if(<condition>) {
    list.add(object.getParam());
}
if(<condition>) {
    list.add(object.getParam());
}
if(<condition>) {
    list.add(object.getParam());
}
(...)
```

Maybe there is cleaner way to do it by stream for example?

Comment: Try a switch block?

Comment: So you want a kind of "delta" between two objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Java library that can "diff" two Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001400/is-there-a-java-library-that-can-diff-two-objects)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (a) {
    case condition1:
        list.add(val);
        break;
    case condition2:case condition3:
        list.add(val);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

so, you mean this.

Comment: It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.