# Best way to check which fields (variables) of 2 Objects of the same class are different (in JAVA 8)?

Tags: java

So, suppose i have the following class:

```
public class Example {
   public int id,
   public String name,
   public double value,
   public int qty,

   public Example(int id, String name, double value, int qty){
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.value = value;
      this.qty = qty;
   }
}
```

Then suppose i have the 2 objects:

```
Example example1 = new Example(1, "1", 1.0, 1);
Example example2 = new Example(2, "1", 2.0, 1);
```

How could i check for each field which are different from each other, without having to have a "if" statement for each field?

Edit: I need to save the history of the change in my database (like: "Value changed from 1.0 to 2.0"). That's why I need to check for the individual fields. And my class irl actually has a LOT more fields, and i'll need to do this for another classes as well. That's why I'm looking for something to do this programatically.

Comment: serialize to json and compare two strings

Comment: @IłyaBursov But how would i know which fields in particular are different? I would have to compare each field of the json instead of the whole string?

Comment: if you need to know what fields are different - you need to compare each field, there is no way around it

Comment: and what output are you expecting? If the names and values of the fields are needed, you can use reflection - see methods of the `Class` class, like [getDeclaredFields](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields())

Comment: @user16320675 I need to save the history of the change in my database (like: "Value changed from 1.0 to 2.0"). That's why I need to check for the individual fields. And my class irl actually has a LOT more fields, and i'll need to do this for another classes as well. That's why I'm looking for something to do this programatically.

Comment: this information is better added to the question. (my previous suggestion is still valid)

Comment: @user16320675 I've seen some answers about reflection. But i didn't quite understand how would I get the values (and also i'll have to mind null values like for the String in this example).

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001400/

Comment: By the way, that kind of audit trail is often best done within the database rather than your app.