# How to get a readable output of the difference between two objects - like AssertJ, but without throwing an AssertionError?

Tags: java, kotlin, validation

My company is currently using AssertJ matchers for production validation, because it prints a readable diff of the two values compared. However, this means we have a lot of try/immediate catch blocks around just for this validation, where we discard the stack trace because we just want to log the diff.

Is there a way to fluently compare two values and get a readable output without throwing an Error? If there's a good way using the standard library, that would be great. But I'm happy to consider any suggestions.

For reference, AssertJ is called like this:

```
Assertions.assertThat(valueB)
    .usingComparatorForType(BigInteger::compareTo, BigInteger::class.java)
    .isEqualToComparingFieldByField(valueA)
```

and outputs something like this:

```
Error during validation between value A and value B: 
Expecting values:
  <[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]>
in fields:
  <["field1",
    "field2",
    "field3",
    "field4",
    "field5"]>
but were:
  <[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]>
in <ValueA(field1=5, field2=6, field3=7, field4=8, field5=9)>.
Comparison was performed on all fields
```

Comment: This answer in this question maybe is not valid to your question, but the general discussion might be beneficial as it is on the same subject: [How to test for equality of complex object graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411612/how-to-test-for-equality-of-complex-object-graphs).

Comment: @AlexT this just uses reflection to check the contents of the fields, but does nothing about logging them. The OP is using asserts mainly for just logging the data and discarding the AssertionErrors.

so OP, try to look into AssertJ's source to see how they're printing it, and copypaste that code :)

Comment: An interesting point from @AlexT's link is that Hamcrest does actually support using matchers for validation without throwing errors, including the readable comparison. I might look into that option.

Comment: FYI, rule 3: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks, @Tenfour04 I'll reword the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields method inside the Objects class, which is inside the AssertJ library. Since the method is private, it will need to be called using reflection. Example:

Comparator.java

```
package objectComparator;

import org.assertj.core.error.ErrorMessageFactory;
import org.assertj.core.error.ShouldBeEqualToIgnoringFields;
import org.assertj.core.internal.Objects;
import org.assertj.core.internal.TypeComparators;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.*;

public class Comparator {
    public static String compare(Object actual, Object other) {
        try {
            Objects objects = Objects.instance();
            // Получаем класс объекта Objects
            Class<?> clazz = objects.getClass();
            // Получаем приватный метод по имени
            Method privateMethod = clazz
                    .getDeclaredMethod("isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields", Object.class, Object.class, Map.class, TypeComparators.class, String[].class);
            // Разрешаем доступ к приватному методу
            privateMethod.setAccessible(true);
            // Вызываем приватный метод с передачей аргументов
            Objects.ByFieldsComparison comparison = (Objects.ByFieldsComparison) privateMethod.invoke(objects, actual, other, new HashMap<String, java.util.Comparator<?>>(), new TypeComparators(), new String[0]);

            ErrorMessageFactory error = ShouldBeEqualToIgnoringFields.shouldBeEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(actual,
                    (List<String>) getComparisonField(comparison, "fieldsNames"),
                    (List<Object>) getComparisonField(comparison, "expectedValues"),
                    (List<Object>) getComparisonField(comparison, "rejectedValues"),
                    Collections.emptyList());

            return error.create();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static List<?> getComparisonField(Objects.ByFieldsComparison comparison, String fieldName) {
        try {
            // Получаем класс объекта ByFieldsComparison
            Class<?> clazz = comparison.getClass();
            // Получаем приватное поле по имени
            Field privateField = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            // Разрешаем доступ к приватному полю
            privateField.setAccessible(true);
            // Получаем значение приватного поля
            return (List<?>) privateField.get(comparison);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the ShouldBeEqualToIgnoringFields.shouldBeEqualToIgnoringGivenFields method is optional. You can remove the call to this method. And parse the result as you need.

Main.java

```
package objectComparator;
    
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person bart = new Person(5, "Bart");
        Person liza = new Person(4, "Liza");

        System.out.println(Comparator.compare(bart, liza));
    }
}
```

Person.java (Sample POJO class)

```
package objectComparator;

public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```